# Matching a pattern with sed and getting an integer out at the same time

Tags: shell, awk, sed, integer, pattern-matching

I have an xml file with these lines (among others):

```
#Env=DEV2,DEV3,DEV5,DEV6
#Enter your required DEV environment after the ENV= in the next line: 
Env=DEV6
```

I need to:

1. Verify that the text after `ENV=` is of the pattern `DEV{1..99}`
2. extract the number (in this case, 6) from the line `ENV=DEV6` to some environment variable

I know a bit of awk and grep, and can use those to get the number, but I'm thinking of Sed, which I'm told matches patterns nicer than awk and takes less time. Also, I'm concerned about long long lines of greps matching the beginning of the line for that particular Env= .

How would I go about doing it with Sed? would I get away with a shorter line?

I'm a sed newbie, read a bunch of tutorials and examples and got my fingers twisted trying to do both things at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
var=$(sed -nE 's/^Env=DEV([0-9]{1,2})$/\1/p' file)
echo "$var"
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: ITYM `/^Env=DEV([1-9][0-9]?)$/\1/p`

Answer (score 2):

Can use `grep` also if `pcre` regex is available

```
$ cat ip.txt
#Env=DEV2,DEV3,DEV5,DEV6
#Enter your required DEV environment after the ENV= in the next line: 
Env=DEV6
foo
Env=DEV65
bar
Env=DEV568

$ grep -xoP 'Env=DEV\K[1-9][0-9]?' ip.txt
6
65
```

- `-x` match whole line
- `-o` output only matching text
- `-P` use `pcre` regex
- `Env=DEV\K` match `Env=DEV` but not part of output
- `[1-9][0-9]?` range of `1` to `99`

Answer (score 1):

You can used `sed` as

```
$ sed 's/^Env=DEV\([1-9][0-9]\?\)/\1/' file
6
```

You can directly use the above command in `export` command as

```
export YOUR_EXPORT_VARIABLE=$(sed 's/^Env=DEV\([1-9][0-9]\?\)/\1/' file)
```

(or) its pretty straight forward with `perl`

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if /Env=DEV.*?(\d+)/' file
6
```

Comment: ITYM `/^Env=DEV\([1-9][0-9]\?\)$/\1/`

Comment: Another brainless downvote? To whoever did it, care to explain why? it was `2` few hours back.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, there is a serious plague of blind down voting , going around, :(

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'Env=DEV' '/Env=DEV[0-9]$|Env=DEV[0-9][0-9]$/{print $2}' input
```

Input:

```
echo '
Env=DEV6
Env=DEVasd
Env=DEV62
Env=DEV622'
```

Output:

```
awk -F'Env=DEV' '/Env=DEV[0-9]$|Env=DEV[0-9][0-9]$/{print $2}' input
6
62
```

To store it into any variable:

```
var=$(awk command)
```

Comment: ITYM `/Env=DEV[1-9][0-9]?$/`

Answer (score 1):

In awk. First some test cases:

```
$ cat file
foo
Env=DEV0
Env=DEV1
Env=DEV99
Env=DEV100
$ awk 'sub(/^Env=DEV/,"") && /^[1-9][0-9]?$/' file
1
99
```