# sed or awk for matching a pattern with a variable from a previous script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

In continuation of this:
[Matching a pattern with sed and getting an integer out at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718708/matching-a-pattern-with-sed-and-getting-an-integer-out-at-the-same-time/40725670#40725670)

Having gotten the number out of a pattern in an xml file, I have a `var_number=some number` ,

`var_number=6` in this case.

In the same xml file, developers ought to enter the following line:

```
NewC_server_list=C_SME_DEV6,C_WEB_DEV6
```

I need to verify that the pattern after the = is C_SME_DEV${var_number},C_WEB_DEV${var_number}

Meaning two things:

1. That the guys entered the server name correctly: C_WEB_DEV and C_SME_DEV,
2. And that the number is the same as var_number (in this case, 6)

sed or awk? My concerns are: shorter script and speed (cpu allocation is lowsy on this machine)

Comment: Have you tried to write something yourself? If yes, show us some of your code.

Comment: What should it output in case that the verification succeeds/fails? Also, is the text on the next line or just about anywhere in the file?

Comment: Show us what you tried before. Hint: to declare variables in an awk command, use the following syntax `awk -v myVar="abc" '/*awk script*/' myfile`. Also, I'm pretty sure you could do what you want in one awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to my previous answer to OP's previous question linked to the question above. Test file:

```
$ cat file
#Env=DEV2,DEV3,DEV5,DEV6
#Enter your required DEV environment after the ENV= in the next line. 
Env=DEV6
NewC_server_list=C_SME_DEV6,C_WEB_DEV6
```

Solution:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^Env=DEV/,"") && /^[1-9][0-9]?$/ {a=$0;b="NewC_server_list=C_SME_DEV" $0 ",C_WEB_DEV" $0} $0==b {print a}' file
6
```

Due to lack of better knowledge it only supports 1 match per file assuming the new requirement data exists after the old.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number from the earlier command is stored in a variable, `myVar`, you can do something like this in `perl`.

Also you can directly run the commands from command-line.

```
#!/bin/bash

myVar=$(perl -nle 'print $1 if /ENV=DEV.*?(\d+)/' file) # stored from your previous question.
# myVar=6  (The value from your previous question)

if (( myVar == $(perl -nle 'print $1 if /.*=C_SME_DEV.*?(\d+)/' file) )) && \
     (( myVar == $(perl -nle 'print $1 if /.*,C_WEB_DEV.*?(\d+)/' file) )); then
     echo "Match found"
fi
```